# How to Avoid Text String Must be rendered within a <Text> component Issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error:Invariant Violation: Text string must be renderd within
>   a component. this error is located at: in RCTView in RCTView in
>   p in v in RCTView in RCTView  in c

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    placeName: "",
    places: []
  }
  placeNameChangedHandler = val => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: val
    });
  };

  placeSubmitHandler = () => {
    if (this.state.placeName.trim() === "") {
      return;
    }
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        places: prevState.places.concat(prevState.placeName)
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const placesOutput = this.state.places.map((place,i) => (
      <Text key={i}> 
       </Text>
    ));
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter Your Name?"
            defaultValue={this.state.placeName}
            onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}
            style={styles.PlaceInput}

          ></TextInput>
          <Button
            title="Add"
            style={styles.placeButton}
            onPress={this.placeSubmitHandler} />
        </View>
        <View>  </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 26,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  inputContainer: {
    // flex:1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "100%"
  },
  PlaceInput: {
    width: "70%"
  },
  placeButton: {
    width: "30%"
  }
});
```

Comment: What have you recently added to cause the error, which specific piece of code causes this? Could you add some more detail on things you've tried already? From all I can see in the render function you call an empty <Text> component, but I don't think that brings up the error.

Comment: actually till now , i can not know which part of code is responsible about error ..i spent more than hour :(

Comment: Try self-closing `<Text key={i} />`, the `<TextInput />` and the `<View />` at the end

Comment: Also notice that you can't pass a prop `style` to a react-native `<Button>`. Use instead a `<TouchableOpacity>` if you want to customize it

Comment: @Milore your soultion working fine for me, ,i posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Self Closing For Components working fine for me, As the following:

```
<View/>
```

Instead of:

```
 <View> </View>
```

And

```
<TextInput
            placeholder="Enter Your Name?"
            defaultValue={this.state.placeName}
            onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}
            style={styles.PlaceInput}
          />
```

Instead of:

```
  <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter Your Name?"
            defaultValue={this.state.placeName}
            onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}
            style={styles.PlaceInput}
          ></TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to the use of the map() function, if you use it for JSX you should explicitly return (implicit return for JSX is somehow not supported):

```jsx
render() {
  const placesOutput = this.state.places.map((place,i) => {
    return(<Text key={i}> </Text>);
 })
```

But I don't really see what you are doing with this placesOutput variable?

Comment: I was used it on last view, but i deleted to figure out , what is the part responsible about error ?